# General questions regarding Bakoma

Tags: bakoma

1. How do I enter a mathematical symbol like alpha or Beta? Is there a nice keyboard shortcut like CTRL-beta (as in scientific workplace)?
2. Can I define my own keyboard shortcuts?
3. How do I paste figures from MATLAB?
4. Can I give names to MY references, equations and figures, etc. like `eq:LagrangeFormula`? Like automatic referencing.
5. How many formats/packages do I have?
6. Can the output be read by regular LaTeX software?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would courteously suggest you to take a look at [this overview of the site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour). Generally speaking a good question here does not involve several questions related to different topics (figures, references, input).

Answer (score 4):

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> A inserts alpha
2. Yes, read "Help / Using the Keyboard"
3. save figures in most common graphics formats then import them
4. Yes. LaTeX references are supported.
5. TeXWord can use any LaTeX package compatible with e-TeX.
6. Yes.